# Изменение аватара контакта в amocrm

Tags: javascript, php, виджет, crm

Хочу изменить аватар контакта
[image: Аватар контакта]

В документации amocrm.ru/developers ни чего подходящего не нашел
Подскажите программные интерфейсы, для изменения аватара

Comment: При добавлении изображения у контакта и получения его (контакта) из API какие данные изменяются проверяли? В самом API действительно нет примеров для изображения профиля, но можно пойти таким экспериментальным путём.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov да проверял, в объекте из api/v2/contacts?id=ххх данные об аватаре не пришли